# How do I enable and publish code coverage?

Tags: code-coverage

This is the dotnet test command that I am using to test and publish code coverage, but it is not publishing code coverage. What am I doing wrong?

dotnet test $TestProjectDirectory --results-directory $TestResultsDirectory --collect:"XPlat Code Coverage" --logger "trx;LogFileName=$LogFileName" -p:CoverletOutput=$CoverageResultsDirectory -p:CollectCoverage=true -p:CoverletOutputFormat=cobertura